# Retrive Value automatically from XML file with Javascript and respond

Tags: javascript, xml

I have following code in HTML, and I would like to retrieve "name12@host.com" from XML file called "XMLSMAPLE.XML" automatically.

**In coding, the flow should be like :**

Select "name12@host.com" in XML files automatically and get values from attributes and assign values in javascript and show the output in screen.

> `<div id="email">name12@host.com</div> <div id="point"></point><div class="order"><span class="date"></span><span class="quantity"></span></div><div class="redeem"><span class="date"></span><span class="id"/></span></div>`

XMLSAMPLE.XML

```
    </UserInfo>


<UserInfo emailaddress="yourname@host.com" zipcode="12345" point="12">
<order date="12/12/12" quantity="121" />
<order date="11/12/12" quantity="191" />
<order date="14/12/12" quantity="101" />
<redeem date="11/12/12" id="amex" quantity="1" value="25" />
<redeem date="11/12/12" id="homedepot" quantity="2" value="100" />

    </UserInfo>


<UserInfo emailaddress="name12@host.com" zipcode="12345" point="12">
<order date="12/12/12" quantity="121" />
<order date="11/12/12" quantity="191" />
<order date="14/12/12" quantity="101" />
<redeem date="11/12/12" id="amex" quantity="1" value="25" />
<redeem date="11/12/12" id="homedepot" quantity="2" value="100" />

    </UserInfo>


</Users>
```

**So, In respond, you get output as following:**

```
<div id="email">name12@host.com</div> <div id="point">12</point>
<div class="order">
<span class="date">12/12/12</span><span class="quantity">121</span>
<span class="date">11/12/12</span><span class="quantity">191</span>
<span class="date">14/12/12</span><span class="quantity">101</span>
</div>
<div class="redeem">
<span class="date">11/12/12</span><span class="id"/>amex</span>
<span class="date">11/12/12</span><span class="id"/>homedepot</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Jquery this is how i do it:
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/xml-parsing-with-jquery

for example:

```
//find every UserInfo and place the point in a html

  $(xml).find("Tutorial").each(function()
  {
    $("#output").append($(this).attr("point") + "<br />");
  });
```

You can also use XSLT and XPath if you want to skip the javascript part.

**EDIT #1**:

```
  $(xml).find("Tutorial").each(function()
  {
    if($(this).attr("emailaddress")=="name12@host.com"){
       $("#output").append($(this).attr("point") + "<br />");
    }        
  });
```

Comment: The problems is it is showing lists of XML phrasing which node has Tutorials. 

I am using this way. http://think2loud.com/reading-xml-with-jquery/ But I need to retrieve only one section which has attributes called "name12@host.com".

Comment: Can you put an if statement like my EDIT #1?

Answer (score 0):

The 'find' function accepts a selector, of which an xpath query is a valid example.  Therefore, try this:

```
$(xml).find('//Users/UserInfo[@emailaddress="name12@host.com"]').each(function() {
  // do something with the located xml node
  var orders = $(this).find('order');
  var redeems = $(this).find('redeem');
});
```